# No supported color terminal library Python/Jupyter

Tags: python, windows, tornado, jupyter

I'm trying to start a Jupyter Notebook server on my Windows 7 machine, but I keep getting this odd, seemingly unsearchable error after typing:

```
jupyter notebook
```

into cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\zfleeman>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 9, in <modul
e>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 267, in
 launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657
, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87,
 in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1290, in in
itialize
    super(NotebookApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in initialize
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87,
 in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 239, in
 initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1007, in pa
rse_command_line
    super(NotebookApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87,
 in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 536
, in parse_command_line
    flags=flags, log=self.log)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 556, in __ge
t__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 226
, in _log_default
    _log_formatter = self._log_formatter_cls(fmt=self.log_format, datefmt=self.l
og_datefmt)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\log.py", line 154, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("No supported color terminal library")
RuntimeError: No supported color terminal library
```

This looks like more of a Windows problem than a Python problem. Can somebody give me some advice? I just need to launch my Notebook server.

Comment: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2013

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just had the same problem!. As Ben said, apparently is an error of Tornado 4.5

I solved installing the previous package, Tornado 4.4.3

```
pip install tornado==4.4.3
```

And then I just run the Jupyter Notebook in `cmd.exe`:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Tornado 4.5.1 has now been released to solve this issue, so you can upgrade to that version instead of downgrading to 4.4.3

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `colorama` installed? This looks like an error in the just-released Tornado 4.5 if you have `colorama` installed but do not call `colorama.init()`.

Comment: Thanks Ben. The situation you describe (colorama installed but not used) is likely to be common for Jupyter notebook users on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Disable color:
In file `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\log.py` on line 112 look for `color=True` and change it to `color=False`.
Or install curses module for Windows from [this repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses)

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? Great to have something that'll get the OP past their immediate hurdle, but it would be even better to help them understand WHY this error occurred, and what this solution does to fix or work around the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same jupyter problem for Python 2.7 on windows 10 upon updating the Anaconda Python distribution.
setting color=False for Tornado log file helped solve the problem.